# Solidity ParserError Expected ',' but got 'Number'

Tags: solidity

When compiling the following code on Remix:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.7;

    function canWithdraw(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (bool) {
    if (auctions[tokenId].open && 
        (
            (
                now >= auctions[tokenId].auctionEnd &&
                auctions[tokenId].highestBid > 0 &&
                auctions[tokenId].highestBid 0) {
        (bool success, ) = auctions[tokenId].highestBidder.call.value(auctions[tokenId].highestBid)("");
        require(success, "Transfer failed.");
    }
```

Im getting this error:

```
Re.sol:1508:50: ParserError: Expected ',' but got 'Number'
auctions[tokenId].highestBid 0) {
^
```

What do you think it could be? How can I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: You can remove `&& auctions[tokenId].highestBid 0`

Comment: Getting this error then: Expected ',' but got '{'
auctions[tokenId].highestBid > 0) {

Comment: added my answer with fixed the `(`

Comment: also, you need to use visual studio code with `solidity` extension to check solidity grammer

Comment: You should set a comparison operator (`==` or `!=` or `<` or `>` or like these) between `auctions[tokenId].highestBid` and `0` in line 9. Then you also get error. To solve that add enough `)` to the end of comparisons (I mean after `auctions[tokenId].highestBid 0`. 2x `)` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
function canWithdraw(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (bool) {
    if (
        auctions[tokenId].open &&
        now >= auctions[tokenId].auctionEnd &&
        auctions[tokenId].highestBid > 0
    ) {
        (bool success, ) = auctions[tokenId].highestBidder.call.value(
            auctions[tokenId].highestBid
        )("");
        require(success, "Transfer failed.");
    }
}
```